# Unable to send mail using Gmail API in Java

Tags: java, gmail-api

I am trying to send a mail using my gmail account. I have done the following steps -

(i) Created a service account in developers console.
(ii) Obtained the private key file.
(iii) Used that private key file in my code.

Code -

```
package com.gmail.test;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.repackaged.org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.Gmail;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.GmailScopes;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.model.Message;



public class GmailOauthTest {

      public static void sendMessage(Gmail service, String userId, MimeMessage email)
          throws MessagingException, IOException {
        Message message = createMessageWithEmail(email);
        // message = service.users().messages().send(userId, message).execute();
        message = service.users().messages().send(userId, message).execute();

        System.out.println("Message id: " + message.getId());
        System.out.println(message.toPrettyString());
      }

      public static Message createMessageWithEmail(MimeMessage email)
          throws MessagingException, IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        email.writeTo(baos);
        String encodedEmail = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(baos.toByteArray());
        Message message = new Message();
        message.setRaw(encodedEmail);
        return message;
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {

        String emailAddress = "#############@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
        JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
        try {
            HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

            File file = new File(p12File);

            Set<String> scopes = new HashSet<String>();
            scopes.add(GmailScopes.GMAIL_SEND);
            scopes.add(GmailScopes.GMAIL_COMPOSE);

            GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                    .setTransport(httpTransport)
                    .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                    .setServiceAccountId(emailAddress)
                    .setServiceAccountUser(userAccount)
                    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(file)
                    .setServiceAccountScopes(scopes)
                    .build();
            Gmail gmail = new Gmail
                    .Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                    .setApplicationName(ApplicationName)
                    .build();

            Properties props = new Properties();
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            message.addRecipient(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
            message.setSubject("Test Mail");
            message.setText("Test Mail");
            sendMessage(gmail, "me", message);


        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the following exception -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.api.client.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:191)
    at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:127)
    at com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory.createJsonParser(JacksonFactory.java:92)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:85)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:81)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException.from(TokenResponseException.java:88)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:287)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:307)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.executeRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:384)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:489)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.intercept(Credential.java:217)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:859)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
    at com.gmail.test.GmailOauthTest.sendMessage(GmailOauthTest.java:44)
    at com.gmail.test.GmailOauthTest.main(GmailOauthTest.java:101)
```

I saw a few other threads, but was not able to find a solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you trying to use your own gmail account with the service account? in this parameter "setServiceAccountUser"

Comment: @Gerardo - Yes. I am using the google account that I used to create the service account in setServiceAccountUser.

Comment: Although the null pointer exception is strange,  one problem is that you cannot use a gmail account with service account. When you are using this method for authentication is called "impersonation" or "delegation of authority". in which the service account would impersonate the user and act on his behalf. So you cannot impersonate a gmail user, even if its the same account you used to create the service account.  this scenario is only valid for Domain accounts. https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation

Comment: @Gerardo - Actually, I did try without setting the service user account. But that was giving me some other issue. Will post that in some time.